# Probability of an event occurring, based on percentage win rate of each player

Tags: python, java, probability

The scenario is:
p1_win_rate = 0.6;
p2_win_rate = 0.3;

What are the percentage chances of Player 1 (with the win skill rate of 60%) to win against Player 2 (with the win skill rate of 30%), taking in account each player win percentage rate.

I came out with the basic formula:

p1_win_chance = p1_win_rate/(p1_win_rate + p2_win_rate);  // in this scenario => p1_win_chance =(0.6/(0.6 + 0.3)) = 0.6666 (approx)

p2 = 1 - p1_win_chance;  // p2_win_chance = 1 - 0.6666 = 0.3333 (approx).

Should I use a loop with random simulation and if yes, how this can be implemented knowing that p1 has a double win rate than p2 but still, 60% win rate doesn't seems to be a very promising win rate. Therefore, p2 may win 1 of 3 duels, 1 of 4 or 1 of 2.

I have a feeling that I'm not using the correct formula. Or I am overcomplicating this?

Comment: Hi, I won 60% of the duels but against different players with different win rate (let's say between 30% and 75%), but against a player with a win rate of 30%, I think I may have more chances to win than just my 60% average.

Comment: 60% is twice as good as 30%, so the 60% will win 2/3 vs 1/3 for the 30%. Your formula is correct (making lots of assumptions about all players, of course)

Comment: In general you cannot reason about skill based on the win rate, unless you everyone has very many games and no skill based matchmaking but simply random player against random player. But on a very simple level your math checks out.